# Google Maps showing blank screen only on iOS testers device

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps-sdk-ios, geolocator

i have recently uploaded an app to App Store review and after several attempts to make location work, I think I made it.

The problem is that my map is not loading at all, it only shows a blank page according to app store reviewers. This is kind of odd because if I download the same version from TestFlight it works perfectly fine on my phone and also in emulators while debugging... What could it be?

From the app start to that point, there is a loading page that fetches some info from Firebase Firestore and a service that access user's location using GeoLocator. If the app stopped loading it means that is has an error or it has successfully loaded the information and the location. If there is an error, a modal should be displayed and the app store testers didn't mention any modal so I guess the information was loaded correctly...

I am already using Firebase Crashlytics to detect unhandled exception but I am not receiving anything. Also I tried to register the handled exceptions but also I am not receiving them in the console...

App Store testers image

[image]

I have to mention that my API keys are added in GoogleService-Info.plist and AppDelegate.swift:

```
// GoogleService-Info.plist
...
<key>API_KEY</key>
<string>my_api_key</string>
...
```

```
// AppDelegate.swift
...
GMSServices.provideAPIKey("my_api_key")
FirebaseApp.configure() //add this before the code below
GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
...
```

The last change I made was changing the location package to GeoLocator and I think it solved an issue I had (it loaded indefinitely, I assume it got stuck while getting user's location).

Comment: Apple testers test under extreme conditions. What does your app do if there's no network?